# the embed do not send and i didint have errors

Tags: python, discord.py, embed

```
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@bot.command()
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.send (f"{member.mention} text  {ctx.guild.name}  for the reason: {reason} ")
    await  member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send (title=f"**__text:__**", description=f"{member.mention} \n  **text:** \n *{reason}*", timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),color=discord.Color.blue()) .embed.set_footer (text="text ", icon_url="url")
    if reason is None:
        reason = f"{member.mention} was banned without reasons {ctx.guild.name} "
        return reason
```

i dont have errors and the embed didint send

Comment: The syntax of the 5th line is not really a valid python syntax

Comment: ?????????? it is

Comment: i use discord py{member.mention} it’s on discord py read the docs maybe and I used f string

Comment: No, not that, this - `timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),color=discord.Color.blue()) .embed.set_footer (text="text ", icon_url="url")`

Comment: Oh yeah maybe it’s doesn’t working so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you a better division to minimize the sources of errors. The best way is to define an embed.

***Have a look at the following code:***

```py
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@bot.command()
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.send(f"{member.mention} text  {ctx.guild.name}  for the reason: {reason} ")
    await member.ban(reason=reason)

    embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.blue())
    embed.title = "__Text__" # Title is always bold
    embed.description = f"{member.mention} \n  **text:** \n *{reason}*"
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow() # New timestamp
    embed.set_footer(text="This is a test", icon_url="PassUrl")
    await ctx.send (embed=embed) # Send defined embed

    if reason is None:
        reason = f"{member.mention} was banned without reasons {ctx.guild.name} "
        return await ctx.send(f"{reason}")
```

Also pay attention to proper indentation, possibly too many spaces, etc.

*Maybe also have a look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed) and how to create a valid embed.*

Comment: hmm i see i tried to add many embeds in 1 line of code thanks for the support !

Comment: You can also put it in one line but this could lead to errors which you will not see in the first place. Having it like this your program should tell you what you are doing wrong (PyCharm for example).